# Can I use "among" instead of "in" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Can I use "among" instead of "in" in this sentence?

> Test results showed that it could slow memory loss by as much as 17% **in** patients if taken regularly and in combination with other prescribed medication."

If I can't, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.  This is because the *it* referred to in your sentence slows memory loss *in* each individual patient, not collectively amongst multiple patients as a group.

Answer (score 1):

Different meanings of different statements are:

> The trials indicated that the medication could reduce dementia in 17% of patients who take it regularly.

It is indicated that the medication works only on 17% of people.

.................................

> The trials indicated that the medication could reduce dementia by 17% in patients who take it regularly.

It is indicated that the medication works for [nearly] every member of the whole population effecting an average of 17% reduction per person.

.................................

> The trials indicated that the medication could reduce dementia by 17% among patients who take it regularly.

It is indicated that the medication is effective among people, but it does not indicate who among those, who take it regularly. For those in which the medication is effective, the reduction is indicated to be 17%.